# Compare strings that may or may not contain only numbers java

Tags: java, string, integer, comparison

I'm making an online IDE kind of thing and my response comes in JSON format which I convert to String.

Then, I compare the output with certain "test cases" to see if the program does what is expected. (Kind of a [HackerRank](http://www.hackerrank.com) thing)

The questions are in a database and they have their testcases and expected output which I later on write in a file and then give it to the command and compare the output with the expected output that I also get from the file.

My problem lies at, when I compare strings, it works perfectly but, say, I have only integers that are supposed to be like this:

1

2

and the expected output is also

1

2

**EDIT AGAIN**

This is how I'm getting stdout

```
public String funcStdout(String command)
{
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    String res="";
     Object obj;
    try {
        obj = parser.parse(command);
         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            res = (String) jsonObject.get("Stdout");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;
    }
```

This is how im getting expout

```
public String getExpOutput1(int id){
            Connection conn = null;
            String result = ""; 
            try {
                conn = Database.getMySQLConnection();
                String sql = "select exp_output1 from Questions where question_id = ?";
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, id);

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    result= rs.getString(1);

                    return result;

                }


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                  return result;


        }
```

[image: Image to show how it looks like]

Comment: output and exoutput are String?  The first is what you want but it is not clear why you are not getting true from what you have said (unless there are newlines embedded in the strings or something else is going on, like character codes.  == tests won't work for your purposes unless the objects are the same. You seem to want to check on the contents of different objects so .equals is the way to go.

Comment: @jwd630 Yes, sir! They are

Comment: did you try trimming strings maybe there is an extra space

Comment: Are you sure that the two are completely equal? Is it possible that some other character (like more white space) could be in the expected output? Try printing out the two before or after comparing them to see what each one looks like (compare with your eyes :P).

Comment: can you please put some code snippet showing how exactly you are populating these two strings

Comment: @singhakash I can't afford trimming them. I want the newlines to be compared.

Comment: Check if they have the same length and if so, check if the value of each char really is the same.

Comment: @singhakash the `stdout` comes from a `JSONObject` that is converted to `String`, and `expOut` comes from a text file.

Comment: @YehCheez.. trim() on strings only remove white space characters, it won't trim other characters, so just before you call `equals`, try trimming them like `stdout.trim().equals(expOUt1.trim())`

Comment: `stdout` & `expOUt1`, both are of String type right ?

Comment: @Arkantos yes. And the trim did not work either.

Comment: @Arkantos I have edited question and added image

Comment: @YehCheez.. you can remove the image, it's not helping :) Pls add the code where you're creating `stdout` and `expOUt1` objects

Comment: @Arkantos done it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74865/discussion-between-arkantos-and-yehcheez).